# Stringizing operator # cannot deal with one double quote case

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

For the following code

```
#include <iostream>

#define test(para) std::cout << #para << std::endl

int main() {
    test(Hello"World"!);// two double quotes work well
    test(Hello"World!); // one double quote case has compilation error
    
    test(Hello\nWorld!\n); // OK
    test(Hello\"World!\"); // doesn't work
}
```

Why `test(Hello"World!)` doesn't compile? How to tweak it so that `test(SomeCode)` outputs **Hello"World!** ?

Comment: Even arguments to macros have to form valid C++ tokens. `"World!); // one double quote case has compilation error` isn't a valid C++ token. This simply doesn't work in C++.

Comment: `Hello"World!` is not a valid construct in C++.  If you have an opening `"`, you need a closing `"`.

Comment: Given that this solution path is impossible, maybe there's another way to solve your overall problem, but we don't yet know what that is.

Comment: @chris ...and [raw strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) could be part of that solution. ;-)

Comment: @ Scheff's Cat What makes a valid C++ token? `test(Hello\"World!\");` neither works, though there is a pair of `\"`. I get confused by  the valid token concept.

Comment: See draft C++ [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) Annex A Grammar summary, page 1210.

Comment: Escaping of quotes (`\"`) is allowed/supported/part-of-the-language inside of string literals (to allow usage of quotes inside of quoted text). Using it outside, is not. Thus, this doesn't form a valid token. It's regardless what the preprocessor could make out of it as it fails as input to the preprocessor. (FYI: [Translation Phases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) - `test(Hello\"World!\");` cannot pass [Phase 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases#Phase_3).)